# One array copying data to 2 other arrays using C pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to Programming and to Stack overflow, so forgive me if I make any mistakes. I have this program where one array of ints is split into two other arrays depending on if they are larger or smaller than a user inputted int. Right now all the smaller and larger arrays do is copy the first integer regardless of the number put in. Any suggestions/critiques?

```
/*
  This program will separate an input array into two arrays. One array will be filled by
  elements greater than a specified number and the other array will be filled by elements
  less than the specified number.

*/

#include <stdio.h>

void separate(int *a, int n, int value, int *larger, int *size, int *smaller);

int main()
{

  //Find size of array
  int length;
  int *length_pointer = &length;
  printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", length_pointer);

  //Enter array elements
  int array[length], *p;
  printf("Enter %d numbers: ", length);
  for(p = array; p < array + length; p++)
    scanf("%d", p);

  //Find separating value
  int value;
  printf("Enter the number to split the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &value);

  //Declare arrays and call function
  int n = 0, larger[length], smaller[length];
  separate(array, n, value, larger, length_pointer, smaller);

  //Display the arrays
  printf("%d\n", *smaller);
  printf("%d", *larger);

  return 0;
}

/*************************************************************************************
  separate finds numbers larger than value in array a and stores them in array larger.
  Numbers smaller than or equal to value will be stored in the smaller array.
  size points to a variable in which the function will store the number of larger
  numbers in the array.
*************************************************************************************/
void separate(int *a, int n, int value, int *larger, int *size, int *smaller)
{
  // Delete later *smaller = *larger = *a;
  for(a = &n; a < n + size; a++)
    if(a[n] > value)
    {
      larger = &a[n];
    }
    else if(a[n] <= value)
      smaller = &a[n];

  return;
}
```

Comment: `*smaller = *larger = *a;` is copying the first value of a into the first value of smaller and larger.... is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Oh, now that you say that I can see. No that's not what I wanted. I will have to delete that and test it some more afterwords. My goal is to have an array (let's say 1 2 3 4 5) and two other arrays. Let's say I wanted to split them at 4, so the "smaller" array would contain 1 2 3 4, while "larger" array would contain 5. I'll test it out and see!

Comment: You must set a static array's size before runtime.

Comment: _(let's say 1 2 3 4 5)_ - Is the original array always sorted? Or was this just a  degenerate example?

Comment: It was just a random example it could be any integer in any combination.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a bit your code to reach your goal. In order to get array size from user input under C99, you need to dynamically assign it e.g. by calloc(elements_number, element_size_in_bytes) when your program runs. Don't forget to free assigned memory to avoid memory leaks. Like below:

```
int* array = calloc(user_input, sizeof(int));
...
//some code
...
free(array);
```

Your separate function looks a bit complex. This part is wrong:

```
for(a = &n; a < n + size; a++)
```

What you are doing here is making **a** point to integer **n**. **a** does not point anymore to a source array. So making a call like **a[n]** when **a** is **&n** is like **(&n)[n]**. **n** is not changing value also, because you increment pointer to **n**, not the value it points to.

Next if you want to display array elements do it by using loop, like I did below.

I could not find the purpose of n parameter in your separate function. I used it as amount of real elements in larger array, so I don't have to print all elements.

I hope this answer meats your expectations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void separate(int *a, int *larger_count, int value, int *larger, int size, int *smaller);

int main()
{

    //Find size of array
    int length;
    int *length_pointer = &length;
    printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", length_pointer);

    //Enter array elements
    int*array = calloc(*length_pointer, sizeof(int));
    int*p;
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", length);
    for(p = array; p < array + length; p++)
        scanf("%d", p);

    //Find separating value
    int value;
    printf("Enter the number to split the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    //Declare arrays and call function
    int *larger = calloc(*length_pointer, sizeof(int));
    int *smaller = calloc(*length_pointer, sizeof(int));
    int larger_count = 0;
    separate(array, &larger_count, value, larger, length, smaller);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < larger_count ; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", larger[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < length - larger_count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", smaller[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(array);
    free(larger);
    free(smaller);
    return 0;
}

/*************************************************************************************
  separate finds numbers larger than value in array a and stores them in array larger.
  Numbers smaller than or equal to value will be stored in the smaller array.
  size points to a variable in which the function will store the number of larger
  numbers in the array.
*************************************************************************************/
void separate(int *a, int *larger_count, int value, int *larger, int size, int *smaller)
{
    for(int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        if (a[x] > value)
        {
            larger[y] = a[x];
            y++;
            *larger_count = y;
        } else
        {
            smaller[z] = a[x];
            z++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure if we are allowed to use calloc(I mean I haven't seen it in the textbook nor in lectures), but I'd have to double check but I will write some stuff tonight and you may have given me an idea as to how to rewrite the separate function.

Comment: It depends what language standard are you using. If its atleast C99, setting array size at runtime the way you did it is fine, in other cases you have no choice.

Comment: Alright cool thank you. I believe it is c99 because we have used other features exclusive to c99.